# Password handling in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, passwords

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 application.

In one of my models I am have a password property where I store a password needed to access a web service.  Having this property store the **cleartext password** means that the cleartext password becomes visible in the URL when the associated view is displayed, which cannot be allowed for security reasons.
So I want to have the property store the encrypted password and only decrypt it when it is needed to pass to the web service.

**The problem** I face is that I have a form where the user can enter the password.  I am using one of the asp.net mvc 4 templates (Html.PasswordFor).  In order for the user to enter the cleartext password and for the form to receive it, the password I use here must be cleartext.

What I need is to be able specify two properties in the model.  One of them works with the cleartext password and another one works with the encrypted password.  For this form field, I need to use the cleartext property but I do not want the cleartext password being displayed in the URL.

How can I prevent that?

Is there some attribute I can add to the property that will tell MVC not to automatically send it to the view?

I have a property called password in the model that the view is based on, as follows:

```
<Required()> _
<Display(Name:="Password")> _
Public Property Password() As String
    Get
        Return sPassword
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sPassword = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: You are in control of what you send to the view.  You create the view model.  If you don't want to send the password, simply don't add that property to your view model.  It's that simple.

Comment: Don't I need the property for the Html.PasswordFor field in the form that takes the cleartext password?  If I remove the cleartext password property, then how do I pass values to/from this form field?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself.  You said you didn't want to send it to the view.  If you don't want to send it to the view, then simply don't send it to the view.

Comment: In the view, I have a form field where I allow the user to set the password.  I need that functionality.  They need to be able to type in the cleartext password into a text box (the text box encrypts the password).  This is security safe since the text box is not displaying the cleartext password.  But, if I do this then the URL is showing the clear text password.  What I need (if possible) is to show the encrypted password in the URL but still allow the user to see/enter the cleartext password in the text box.  I just don't want the cleartext password to ever be visible.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. When you say the clear password is shown in the URL, what are you talking about? Are you using GET in the METHOD for the form?

Comment: I am using POST method for the form.  The reason the URL is being displayed is because I have a property for the password in the model that the form is based on.  I am using a strongly-typed view based upon the model.  All properties are being sent to the view in the URL initially when the form is displayed (before submit).  For example:     <Required()> _
    <Display(Name:="Password")> _
    Public Property Password() As String
        Get
            Return sPassword
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            sPassword = value
        End Set
    End Property

Answer (score 0):

Use **POST** not **GET** on a secured connection to send this type of information to the server.
I see no reason why this clear text password should be showing up in the url at all.

**EDIT:**

When you need to setup passwords you probably want to do this in its own form and not as part of an existing form.
Consider having a link inside of the view that triggers the original form, that can be used to trigger another view where you can setup the password.

The model for this individual view is usually Password and PasswordRetyped (having a single input for a password is dangerous as the user can make a typo).

By doing this, you will avoid sending the clear text password to a view EVER.

Comment: I am using post on the form.  The problem is not with the password being displayed when I submit the form.  The problem is with displaying the form initially (before the submit).  I have a property within the model called password: